# I have encountered the following deadlock during a bulk create operation.What could be the possible way to debug this issue?

Tags: postgresql

I went through this article, but still not sure how to debug the following deadlock issue
http://www.moioli.net/progetti/postgres-deadlocks-debugging-guidelines/

```
2018-11-23 07:05:20 UTC:10.20.0.56(56464):treebo_cm@treebo_cm:[3902]:ERROR: deadlock detected
2018-11-23 07:05:20 UTC:10.20.0.56(56464):treebo_cm@treebo_cm:[3902]:DETAIL: Process 3902 waits for ShareLock on transaction 367082736; blocked by process 4259.
Process 4259 waits for ShareLock on transaction 367082737; blocked by process 3902.
Process 3902: UPDATE unirate_rate_v2 SET modified_at='2018-11-23T07:05:19.294912'::timestamp, incoming_request_id=14081278 WHERE unirate_rate_v2.id = 2143917
Process 4259: UPDATE unirate_rate_v2 SET modified_at='2018-11-23T07:05:19.314965'::timestamp, incoming_request_id=14081278 WHERE unirate_rate_v2.id = 12555286
2018-11-23 07:05:20 UTC:10.20.0.56(56464):treebo_cm@treebo_cm:[3902]:HINT: See server log for query details.
2018-11-23 07:05:20 UTC:10.20.0.56(56464):treebo_cm@treebo_cm:[3902]:CONTEXT: while updating tuple (318,57) in relation "unirate_rate_v2"
2018-11-23 07:05:20 UTC:10.20.0.56(56464):treebo_cm@treebo_cm:[3902]:STATEMENT: UPDATE unirate_rate_v2 SET modified_at='2018-11-23T07:05:19.294912'::timestamp, incoming_request_id=14081278 WHERE unirate_rate_v2.id = 2143917
```

Comment: Check your application where you run `UPDATE unirate_rate_v2 SET modified_at ...`

Comment: a bulk create function is being called where all the items are added to the a session
``` session.add_all(items)
    session.flush()```